# EF, get entity tree

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I have EF model and I would like to get list of entities names which are somehow related with parent entity.

Lets say thay I have this model.
[image]

If I choose entity "Orders" I should get as result Orders, Customers, Order_Details nad CustomerDemographics.

It there a way how to do this?
Thank you.

Comment: sure. I'm tying to get all Properties from entitie(using reflection), but I don't know, how recognize Navigation Property..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to get entity names this way and without reflection:

```
using (var context = new ModelContainer())
{
    var container =     context.MetadataWorkspace.GetEntityContainer(context.DefaultContainerName, DataSpace.CSpace);
    var entitySet =     container.BaseEntitySets[someEntityName];
    var navProperties = set.ElementType.Members.Where(member => member.BuiltInTypeKind == BuiltInTypeKind.NavigationProperty).Select(member => member.Name).ToList();
}
```